# Want to update a textview on item delete

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a listview containing productname, price and remove button. A textview just above the listview shows the total price of the products. When user clicks the remove button, item get removed from listview as well as from my local database which is a source of listview. On removing the items the textview should show updated price.

Here is my code.

```
tot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);

    CartDBHandler cartDBHandler = new CartDBHandler(this,null,null,12);
    Cart[] cart= cartDBHandler.databaseToArray();

    for (Cart c: cart) {
        String na = c.getItemname();
        String pr = c.getPrice();
        int p = Integer.valueOf(pr);
        total = total + p;
    }
    Log.i("totala","total = "+total);
    tot.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Comment: what is wrong with this code? where is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I am slightly confused as to what do you mean by showing updated price, since you are removing the whole item from the DB?

I think you need to implement an an OnClickListener on the button in the itemView, and then setting the textView when the button is clicked? Obviously, as you've already implemented methods to delete the item from a DB on the button click, simply add a line to change the textView?

Something like this:

```
TextView price= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
price.setText("DELETED");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
tot.setText(total.toString);
```